# Spying on Classes of the Same Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sendinblue

I'm creating spies for two classes belonging to the same namespace with the goal of expecting each to receive specific arguments:

```
allow(SibApiV3Sdk::SendSmtpEmail).to receive(:new).and_return(seb_send_email)
allow(SibApiV3Sdk::SMTPApi).to receive(:new).and_return(seb_smtp_api)

def seb_send_email
  @seb_smtp_api ||= SibApiV3Sdk::SendSmtpEmail.new(email_params)
end

def seb_smtp_api
  @seb_smtp_api ||= SibApiV3Sdk::SMTPApi.new
end
```

When I do, the second spy fails to work properly and returns the first spied object instead. I suspect this has something to do with it being a namespaced class. Is this the expected behavior and is there an alternative approach for handling namespaced class spies?

Comment: the instance variable name in both methods is the same, so once you call the first method, you have already set the value, thus the `=` of the `||=` doesn't get called, and it just returns the already set value. Perhaps you meant `def seb_send_email; @seb_send_email ||= ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign both to `@seb_smtp_api` variable and that's the source of your problems.

You probably call the `seb_send_email` method first, then it's memoized as `@seb_smtp_api` and when you call `seb_smtp_api` it just returns the memoized value.

You can check that by replacing `allow` with `expect` and see that `SibApiV3Sdk::SMTPApi`'s `new` method is never called.